# Basic shape file display using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, gis, arcgis

Are there any packages that allow for the interactive display of GIS shapefiles?  I'm looking to create a simple GUI that displays simple shapefiles (coastlines, etc) but can't seem to find where to start.  I was originally tasked with doing this in R but I would like to try and use python and Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) supports GIS shape files and has a Python interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of the [shapefile](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) library for reading files, and [shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html) for all the processing of the data.

I have used `shapely` for working with geo data feeds that have been loaded into a database, to work with the point and polygon data.

Per your comments, if you just want to simply display a shapefile in your PyQt app, then really all you need is to convert it to an SVG and display it directly. I have not used [this conversion lib](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py) but I am sure there are more like it. Then you can just use a [QSvgWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsvgwidget.html) to load and display it

Comment: Will shapely display graphically?  That's what I'm having a hard time doing... I don't need anything tremendous in the way of processing, mostly just displaying...

Comment: If all you need is to graphically display a shapefile, then you could just search for shapefile -> svg solutions and simply display an SVG in Qt: https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py as an example